# Laravel Collection Search in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to search from a collection with multiple Value in View page

My collection will have

> 1. product_id
> 2. quantity
> 3. color_id
> 4. size_id
> 5. sold_price

I want to search from this collection with `color_id`, `size_id` and `product_id` in view page so the other values like `quantity` and `sold_price` with respective collection will print inside for loop. Is it possible?

```
@foreach($colors as $color)    
    <tr>
        <td>{{$color->color_name}}</td>            
        @foreach($sizes as $size) 
            <td>                  
                // Here Collection search will be implemented with color_id, size_id
                // and product_id and print respective product price and quantity
            </td> 
        @endforeach 
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection`s have a `filter()` method that iterates over the entries in the `Collection` and returns a subset of records that match a given condition. You can use this in a view with the `@php ... @endphp` directive, then loop over the returned `Collection` and output columns (might make more sense to do new `<tr>`, but that's just a display thing):

```
@foreach($colors as $color)    
<tr>
    <td>{{$color->color_name}}</td>            
    @foreach($sizes as $size) 
    @php 
    $entries = $collection->filter(function($record) use($product, $color, $size){ 
        return $record->color_id == $color->id && $record->size_id == $size->id && $record->product_id == $product->id; 
    }); 
    @endphp
    @foreach($entries AS $entry)
    <td>{{ $entry->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $entry->sold_price }}</td>
    @endforeach
    @endforeach 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Note: To ensure you can check `$color->id`, `$size->id` and `$product->id`, make sure to pass them to the function using `use($product, $color, $size)`.

Answer (score 0):

If its Collection, you can use filter method

```
$collection->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($searchValue) {
return $color_id === $searchValue;
});
```

Comment: need more eq ))

Comment: Yeah, `==` or `===`; depends on how strict you want to be.

Comment: I want to implement inside view and another point there are multiple values i need to check